# Memory leak error in tomcat server even after removed quartz related code

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, quartz-scheduler

I am working on web project based on spring hibernate.I am using c3p0 for connection pooling.Sometimes the server is automatically stopped and showing that

> "The web application registered JDBC driver but failed to unregister"

.And also the following error.

> "The web application appears to have started
>   DefaultQuartzSchelduler_Worker_1 but has failed to stop"
>   [image]

This error is still occurs after i have removed Quartz job related code in my project.I have closed all the stream which causes memory leaks but still I dont know why this is happening.Please help me out regarding this issue  because the project is in live.
Thanks

Comment: i suspect a thread management issue. Please check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126980/servlet-has-started-a-thread-but-failed-to-stop-it-memory-leak-in-tomcat

Comment: how did you solve this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632153/tomcat7-jdbc-datasource-this-is-very-likely-to-create-a-memory-leak